# Laravel Concat to get first name + middle name + last name

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to achieve a search on datatable. Right now, I'm only able to search for first name, middle name and last name etc. However, when searching for the full name (first middle and last name) the search won't work.
image:
[success search for firtname/middle/last](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXKqh.png)
image2:
[not working when searching for fullname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7gTA.png)

In my controller, I'm using the `DB::raw()` concat inside a function.
Here's my code:

```
$query->Where(function($query) use ($s)
    {
    $query->Where(DB::raw("CONCAT('first_name', ' ', 'middle_name')"), 'like', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->orwhere('first_name', 'ilike', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->orWhere('middle_name', 'ilike', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->orWhere('last_name', 'ilike', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->orWhere('email', 'ilike', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->orWhere('cellphone', 'ilike', '%'.$s.'%');
    });
```

Please share any fix or insights on this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
User::where(function($query) use ($input) {
            $query->orWhere(DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name, " ", middle_name," ",last_name)'), 'LIKE', '%' . $input['search'] . '%')
                    ->orWhere('first_name', 'LIKE', "%{$input['search']}%")
                    ->orWhere('middle_name', 'LIKE', "%{$input['search']}%")
                    ->orWhere('middle_name', 'LIKE', "%{$input['search']}%")
                    ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', "%{$input['search']}%")
                    ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%{$input['search']}%")
                    ->orWhere('cellphone', 'LIKE', "%{$input['search']}%");
        });
```

I hope it would work for you.

Comment: Your answer did the magic here. The other examples provided by other worked as well. But I'll go for this one. thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help you :)   if you want then marking this answer as correct.

Comment: what if their are patient who does not have midd_name?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CONCAT_WS function of mysql like this and also there are various way to search, so include that as well:

```
$query->Where(function($query) use ($s)
{
    $query->orwhere('first_name', 'like', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->orWhere('middle_name', 'like', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->orWhere('cellphone', 'like', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->orWhereRaw('CONCAT_WS(" ", trim(FirstName), trim(LastName)) like "%' . $s . '%"');
});
```

Comment: thank you same as Ankita's answer this worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all the inputs here. I really appreciate it. I'm actually new to laravel :)
have a nice day..

Here's my final code by the way, perhaps someone will come searching for the answer one day.
[full filter user controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbeP6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that users might search for names in various ways:

```
$query->Where(function($query) use ($s)
    {
    $query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT('first_name', ' ', 'middle_name')"), 'like', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT('first_name', ' ', 'last_name')"), 'like', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT('last_name', ', ', 'first_name')"), 'like', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT('first_name', ' ', 'middle_name', ' ', 'last_name')"), 'like', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT('last_name', ', ', 'first_name', ' ', 'middle_name')"), 'like', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->orwhere('first_name', 'ilike', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->orWhere('middle_name', 'ilike', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->orWhere('last_name', 'ilike', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->orWhere('email', 'ilike', '%'.$s.'%')
    ->orWhere('cellphone', 'ilike', '%'.$s.'%');
    });
```

Comment: the query parameter at the start, gave an error. I did remove that part and it work. thank you

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was too stupid to copy paste :D Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 collect(explode($terms, ' '))->filter()->each(function ($term) use ($query) {
   $term = '%'.$term.'%';
   $query->where(function ($query) use ($term) {
     $query->where('first_name', 'like', $term)
           ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', $term)
           ->orWhere('..//whatever0', 'like', $term)
     });
   });
```

It will not use any indexes but it was not your question anyways :-)

Comment: thank you :) I used other solution, but I tried this and it works. I better bookmark this as well. Thanks all for the input

Comment: Upvote so when you have reputation it will give points as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is what it worked for me:

```php
$query->where(function ($query) use ($name) {
    $query->orWhereRaw('LOWER(first_name) like LOWER(?)', ["%{$name}%"])
        ->orWhereRaw('LOWER(middle_name) like LOWER(?)', ["%{$name}%"])
        ->orWhereRaw('LOWER(last_name) like LOWER(?)', ["%{$name}%"])
        ->orWhereRaw('LOWER(CONCAT(first_name, \' \', middle_name, \' \', last_name)) LIKE LOWER(?)', ["%{$name}%"]);
});
```